# Is ZRTP for secure multi user group video conferencing?

Tags: conference

I haven't find anywhere specifics about ZRTP's ability for secure encrypted group video/audio conferencing, so I am asking you. I know that OTR does not support multi user group chat, so is that same with ZRTP for multi user group video conferencing. Point me to some good websites (other than Wikipedia.).
And what are the limitations of it?

Answer (score 2):

ZRTP is only used for end-to-end encryption... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZRTP

Since you can't make groups with end-to-end, there are other protocols that would support that https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC (as an example). Afaik - there are just text-chat implementations of this protocol.

Comment: So, just OTR for video/audio. Too bad.